# In PostgreSQL, Creating and appending a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to get an average per type then join the aggregated table as a new column in the original table. Here's a visualization and code of what I'm attempting to do:

```
-- The original table --

ID | Cnt | Type
 1    5     A
 1    6     A   
 2    4     B

-- New Table -- 

ID | Cnt | Type | Avg
 1    5     A     5.5
 1    6     A     5.5
 2    4     B     4.0
```

The code I have written thus far is the following:

```
select AVG(Cnt)
  from old
group by(type)
right join on old
```

But, obviously it's not correct since a syntax error is raised. What would be the fix for this? I apologize in advance if my question is similar to an already existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select o.*, avg(cnt) over (partition by type)  
from old o;
```